# MVP Hold focus and list position with 2 Activities

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, mvp

I haven an application with 2 activities, one is a DataGrid list and the other one is a details activity from a certain entry of the list. They are both on the same layout page:

```
 __________________
|     ListView     |
| - entry 1        |
| - entry 2        |
| - entry 3        |
| - ....           |
| - entry n        |
|------------------|
|   DetailsView    |
|__________________|
```

The dataGrid height is fixed therefore I'm having a ScrollPanel to get to certain entries and if you klick on certain entries.

When I implemented a function to delete an entry. I send a `delete` and after the response OK I get the new list with an `GET` call and refill my dataGrid. So when I, for example delete entry 42, for what you have to scroll down a bit, the entry is deleted and the scrollpanel position stays the same just with the new loaded list, as I want it to. So my next step was to change the details few, so I used my `placeController` to load a new empty DetailsView, because the old selected one was already deleted. But when I call a new `DetailsPlace` my `ListView` changes and the ScrollPanel position is a the beginning of the list (ScrollPanel default state, at the beginning of the list).

But thats not what I want to accomplish, why is the ScrollBar changing after the `goTo(place)` call. Thx for any help.

*UPDATE:*

Another aspect is, is it even a good idea to work with 2 activies in the same layout. or whould it be smarter to compare both into one activity and view:

Kinda like (uiBinder):

```
<g:ResizeLayoutPanel ui:field="listContent" width="100%" height="100%">                             
            <g:ScrollPanel ui:field="listScrollPanel" width="100%" height="250px">
                <c:DataGrid  ui:field='dataGrid' width="100%" height="250px" /> 
            </g:ScrollPanel> 
</g:ResizeLayoutPanel>

<g:ScrollPanel>

    <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" height="100%">    
        <table border="0" width="100%" styleName="{style.detailsTable}">

            <!-- Details Table data -->

        </table><br/>
    </g:HTMLPanel>

</g:ScrollPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ActivityMapper` returns the exact same activity instance as it returned the previous time it was called, then that activity won't be stopped and restarted, or even its "view" detached from the document and reattached.

If you do that for your *list* area, that should fix the scrolling issue.

FYI, the `FilteredActivityMapper` and `CachingActivityMapper` are meant to help in this kind of situation: the first one maps all `DetailsPlace` to some `ListPlace`, and the second takes care of caching the activity for places that are `equals()`; that way, your real `ActivityMapper` can concentrate on creating new activity instances. That being said, I tend to not use those helpers and build the caching within my own `ActivityMapper`s, YMMV.